# Как убрать ошибку syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']'?

Tags: yii2

```
[
    'attribute' => 'type',
    'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'type', HistoryBalance::getSortLabels(), 'type'), 
    ['everyday' => '', 'class' => 'form-control form-control-sm']),
],
```

```
public const HT_EVERYDAY = 'каждый день';
public const HT_OREL = 'игра орел';
public const HT_SAPER = 'игра сапер';
public const HT_DUEL = 'игра дуэль';

public static function getSortLabels() {
    return [
        self::HT_EVERYDAY  => Yii::t('app', self::HT_EVERYDAY),
        self::HT_OREL => Yii::t('app', self::HT_EVERYDAY),
        self::HT_SAPER  => Yii::t('app', self::HT_EVERYDAY),
        self::HT_DUEL  => Yii::t('app', self::HT_EVERYDAY),
    ];
}
```

Comment: 'type'), ['everyday' => '', 'class' => 'form-control form-control-sm']), - кажется, одна из круглых закрывающих скобок здесь лишняя.

Comment: Я так пробовал тогда проблема с запятой

Comment: Так пробовал - это как? Поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: У Вас в вызове Html::activeDropDownList как минимум лишний параметр. Их всего 4: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#activeDropDownList()-detail
Скорее всего второй 'type' - тоже лишний.

Comment: @ИщуPHP-разработчикаВолгоград вы что не видите что написано в в заголовке? Перевожу `синтаксическая ошибка, неожиданная ')', ожидание ']'`

Comment: то есть вместо круглой скобки надо поставить квадратную, закрыть массив

Comment: Неожиданно, в заголовке как раз и написано, что у вас лишняя закрывающая круглая скобка. А если её убрать, то становится видно, что у вас ещё и лишний параметр. Отформатируйте свой код - станет очевиднее, какая скобка лишняя.

Answer (score 1):

```
[
    'attribute' => 'type',
    'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList(
        $searchModel, 
        'type', 
        HistoryBalance::getSortLabels(), 
        [
            'everyday' => '', 
            'class' => 'form-control form-control-sm'
        ]
    ),
]
```